# How can I get the first Hour from a JTable

Tags: java, swing, date, jtable

I have a Jtable as you see on the image:

[image]

and I want to get the earliest Hour from it.

I've tried the following code but it does not always get the right earliest Time.

```
String tinjm="";

if(jTable1.getRowCount()==1){
    System.out.println(jTable1.getValueAt(0, 1).toString());
}else{
    for(int i=0; i<jTable1.getRowCount()-1;i++){
        String k=jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
        String j=jTable1.getValueAt(i+1, 1).toString();

        if(Integer.parseInt(k.substring(0, 2))<Integer.parseInt(j.substring(0, 2))){
            tinjm=k;
        }else{
            tinjm=j;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(tinjm);
}
```

Thank you for your Co-operation.

Comment: this code is fired when i push the button " Calculer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way of formatting the data is suggested by other poster to use custom table renderer, Your logic is comparing between current and next row data but what if the already set value is early then the current comparison ?

Sample code below:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;



public class TestJTable {
    private void init(){
        String[][] rowData = new String[][]{{"0","05:00"},{"1","08:00"},{"3","01:40"},{"4","01:30"},{"5","11:15"},{"6","12:10"}};
        
        String[][] columnNames = new String[][]{{},{}};
        final JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Get Earliest Date");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String[] earliest = findEarliestTime(table).split(":");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Earliest Hour " + earliest[0] + " , Minute : " + earliest[1]);
            }
        });
        
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private String findEarliestTime(JTable table) {
        String earliest = (String)table.getValueAt(0, 1);
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            Date currentDate = null;
            Date earliestDate = null;
            String currentValue = null;
            for(int iDx = 1; iDx < table.getRowCount(); iDx++){
                currentValue = (String)table.getValueAt(iDx, 1);
                currentDate = sdf.parse(currentValue);
                earliestDate = sdf.parse(earliest);
                if(earliestDate.getTime() > currentDate.getTime()){
                    earliest = currentValue;
                }
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return String.valueOf(earliest);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestJTable().init();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

After you straighten your renderer like mKorbel suggested, fix your algorithm. You find the minimum with something in this direction:

```
min = Integer.parseInt(tab.get(0...);
for (int i = 1; i < tab.getRowCount(); i++) {
   num = Integer.parseInt(tab.get(i...)..;
   if (num < min) 
      min = num;
}
```

If you compare pairs it is not going to "work always", which means it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is slightly flawed. You are looping through your rows, looking at the current row (k) and the next row (j). You compare these and which ever one is earlier becomes tinjm. However you do not check if tinjm is already earlier than either k or j. So you result is only ever the earliest of your last two rows.